# In tensorflow serving, what are general rules for model name

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to serve a trained tensorflow saved model, and I want the prediction url something like this:

```
localhost:8501/v1/models/<model_name>:predict, where model_name is like "something1/something2"
```

What I did is set model_name parameter to to `something1/something2`
then run

```
docker run --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "$LOCAL_MODEL_DIR:/models/${MODEL_NAME}" \
    -e MODEL_NAME=${MODEL_NAME} \
    -t tensorflow/serving
```

The command seems working fine,
but when I post predictions to `localhost:8501/v1/models/something1/something2:predict`

I got this error:

```
{ "error": "Malformed request: POST /v1/models/something1/something2:predict" }
```

- The model looks to be properly served by tf serving docker image, I guess I am posting a wrong URL?
- When I changed to model name to NOT contain forward slash, everything is working fine

Comment: I made the same observation when using slashes for the REST API, the main problem apparently being that `/` is a reserved character there.

Note that it works for me when I used the gRPC interface instead, so it is not a general "TF Serving does not support slashes in module names" thing.

However, the obvious workaround of escaping the slashes in the HTTP request (using `%2F` instead) did not fix it for me, as TFS apparently does not decode these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation => "When I changed to model name to NOT contain forward slash, everything is working fine" is pretty good one.

So, to answer your question exactly, General Rules for Model Name are

1. Special Symbols like "*, #, /, etc.." are not allowed
2. Spaces are not allowed. Example: "New Model"
3. None of the Folders, which are involved in the Folder Structure of the Path in which we are planning to save the Model, should have spaces.

Usually, when you export a Model, it will be saved in a path, for example, like,

"/usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/export/1554294699", where 1554294699 is the time stamp when the Model was Saved.

So, during inference, it is sufficient for us just to specify the Model Name as **export**.

During Inference and Predictions, Tensorflow Serving takes care of picking the Latest version of the Model from that folder.